# Protect Subversion data against admin

Tags: apache-http-server, administrator, svn, hosting, password-protection

I am currently setting up a Linux server with multiple SVN projects for my company. My boss wants to have a more or less personal SVN for financial and personal data. His problem is that I, as an admin, have access to his data. Is there a way I can protect his data from me/admin/host, since I am able to change and set up passwords. I have already thought about encryption but this completely removes all benefits of SVN.

Would love to hear your thoughts =)

Comment: What SVN client are you using? With TortoiseSVN you can set up local file repositories and use them in exactly the same way as you would a server. If they are stored on an encrypted/backed-up file store then you get the privacy and usefulness of SVN with a more personal focus.

Comment: yes we are using TortoiseSVN, it must not be local, his goal is to work from different locations using SVN

Comment: I'd be tempted to give him a truecrypt container on a file share and create a file based repository in that. That way it's just a matter of opening the container as a drive, then committing to that instead of a server. So long as he has access to the network he is fine.

Comment: What do you mean with file share? Do you think of a svn in a truecrypt Container? Hm, he also wants to have access outside companies network, but I mean this should be a problem.